# How to pass data from JavaScript to perform math in Laravel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, database, laravel, data-retrieval

I have a working JavaScript code to generate random numbers in every second between a range. I want to pull data from the database using laravel for the max and min value.How can I achieve that?
This is the code,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body  ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="MyRngCtrl">
{{rngESUS}}
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('MyRngCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
       $scope.rngESUS = 0;
       (function update() {
          $timeout(update, 1000 * 1);
          max=5000;//max price
          min=4500;//min price
          $scope.rngESUS = Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
       }());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How are you currently rendering this view?

Comment: Can try running query in Javascript?

Comment: Search for "Laravel AJAX" or "Laravel API". Sounds like you need to create a Laravel route that returns your min and max values and then to request that route from your frontend.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = "{{$name}}";             // name is php variable
    console.log(data);   

    var dataArr = "{{json_encode($data_array)}}";   // data_array is php array
    console.log(dataArr);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the $http service to make requests to the server:

```
app.controller('MyRngCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $http) {
   $scope.rngESUS = 0;
   (function update() {
      $timeout(update, 1000 * 1);
      var max=5000;//max price
      var min=4500;//min price
      $scope.rngESUS = Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);

      //MAKE request
      var config = { params: { rngESUS: $scope.rngESUS } };
      $http.get(url, config)
        .then(function(response) {
          var data = response.data;
          console.log(data);
      }).catch(function(response) {
          console.log("ERROR", response);
      }); 
   }());
});
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)